# How can I use AngularJS data binding with CKEditor?

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor

How should I go about this?

I was able to get the data into CKEditor by using a `textarea` with the `name` attribute matching my model and a `script` tag with `ng:bind-template` to call `CKEDITOR.replace`.

I then made a CKEditor plugin that detects changes and writes them back to the `textarea`. The problem is that the `textarea` looses its event handlers when CKEditor initializes and CKEditor doesn't pickup changes to the `textarea`. This makes me think that I am approaching this the wrong way.

Next I tried using `ng:eval-order="LAST" ng:eval="setupCKEditor()"` and setting up the editor from the `setupCKEditor()` function. This didn't work because even with `ng:eval-order="LAST"` the function is still run before the nodes are created.

I have found that adding a `setTimeout(function () {...},0)` around the `CKEDITOR.replace` helps. Now the only problem is that when it changes the model it doesn't repaint the screen until another field is edited.

`scope.$root.$eval();` seems to fix that.

**Update**

We ended up abandoning this since we could never get it to reliably work. We switched to [TinyMCE with Angular-UI](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce) for a while and then ended up building something custom.

Comment: See this other question:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685530/multiple-4-2-ckeditor-instances-on-one-page-with-angularjs?rq=1][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685530/multiple-4-2-ckeditor-instances-on-one-page-with-angularjs?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of works with the `onchange` plugin from http://alfonsoml.blogspot.com/2011/03/onchange-event-for-ckeditor.html.

```
angular.directive("my:ckeditor", function (expression, compiledElement) {
    return function fn(element) {
        var scope = this;

        setTimeout(function () {
            CKEDITOR.replace("editor-" + index, {extraPlugins: 'onchange'});

            scope.$watch("layers[" + index + "].src", function () {
                if (!CKEDITOR.instances["editor-" + index]) return;
                if (scope[expression] == CKEDITOR.instances["editor-" + index].getData()) return;
                CKEDITOR.instances["editor-" + index].setData(scope[expression]);
            });

            CKEDITOR.instances["editor-" + index].on("change", function () {
                scope[expression] = CKEDITOR.instances["editor-" + index].getData();
                scope.$root.$eval();
            });
        }, 0);
    };
});
```

**Update**

This has only been tested on v0.10.6

Comment: Plz can you share your html part i am not getting what is "my:ckeditor" in angular.directive

Comment: Just add it as an attribute to the textarea. Something like this `<textarea my:texteditor="content" id="editor-1"></textarea>`

Comment: has anyone got a working live example? i tried to implement your directive, but nothing would happen. feels like it's not even used at all... :(

Comment: I just added an update to the question. We used https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce for a while and it worked as advertised.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, attached is a module to provide an [angular directive](https://github.com/esvit/ng-ckeditor).  I've not used it yet, so I can not comment on how well it works/integrates.