# Multiple 4.2 CKEditor instances on one page with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor with angularJS. I have two editor windows as below:

```
    {{ modal.data.text }}
    <textarea
         id="Textarea1"
         data-ck-editor
         data-ng-disabled="modal.action=='delete'"
         data-ng-model="modal.data.text"></textarea>
    {{ modal.data.notes }}
    <textarea
        id="Textarea2"
        data-ck-editor
        data-ng-disabled="modal.action=='delete'"
        data-ng-model="modal.data.notes"></textarea>
```

The application allows a user to select rows in a grid and then the following is executed to populate new data in the modal object. Note that the editor instances are created on start up and not each time a new row is selected.

```
$scope.modal.data = row;
```

I am using the following directive:

```
  app.directive('ckEditor',
        [ function() {
            return {
                require : '?ngModel',
                link : function($scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {

                    var ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0]);

                    ck.on('instanceReady', function() {
                        ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
                    });

                    ck.on('pasteState', function() {
                        $scope.$apply(function() {
                            ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
                        });
                    });

                    ngModel.$render = function(value) {
                        ck.setData(ngModel.$modelValue);
                    };
                }
            };
        } ])
```

When the user selects a row and then a tab the data "sometimes" appears and usually does not.

While testing this I noticed that commenting out the function: ck.on('pasteState', function()  seems to help but then I also have more problems as it seems when I enter data into the CDEditor the model {{ }} don't show that data being updated.

Can someone help by giving me some advice on what I can do. The {{ modal.data.text }} and
the {{ modal.data.notes }} get rendered but the CKEditor windows usually appear with no data in them. Also what's the function of 'pasteState' and how does the AngularJS model get updated when I do keystrokes in the CKEditor window? Final question. Will this even work with multiple editor windows. Will there be two instances of the editor created?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating multiple editors on the fly: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/cPTr7/

Starting with multiple editors and changing values on the fly: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/tBrKQ/1/

Updating on keystroke: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/fMC2p/ (Note: when editing within the plain textarea, ckEditor will parse the text and update it again, wrapping it in HTML)

All have the same directive:

```
app.directive('ckEditor', [function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {

            var ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0]);

            ck.on('pasteState', function () {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
                });
            });

            ngModel.$render = function (value) {
                ck.setData(ngModel.$modelValue);
            };
        }
    };
}])
```

Comment: The code example I got from another place used CKEDITOR.instances[name].destroy(); and ck.on('instanceReady', function ()  Do you think these is necessary?  If I close the window with the editor will it do the same as the destroy ?

Comment: When you close the window the editor will be destroyed all on its own.  If you do that you will probably want a case for when you manually destroy the editor and need to remove the `setData` calls. instanceReady would be needed if you plan to change the modal between the init call and its ready.  It usually isn't needed as the default value is used and the user cannot change the value until its ready.